# mysqli prepared statement not running

Tags: php, mysqli

Having an issue with mysqli prepared statement. My function is suppose to create a new employer in my database but when i remove the api_key parameter the statement does not work again. What is wrong?

```
public function createEmployer($companyName, $email, $password, $confirmPass) {

    $response = array ();

    // First check if user already existed in db
    if (! $this->isEmpExists ( $email )) {



        if ($this->comparePassword ( $password, $confirmPass )) {

            // Generating password hash
            $password_hash = PassHash::hash ( $password );

            // Generating API key
            $api_key = $this->generateApiKey ();

            // insert query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "INSERT INTO company(name, email, password, api_key) values(?, ?, ?, ?)" );
            $stmt->bind_param ( "ssss", $companyName, $email, $password_hash, $api_key);

            $result = $stmt->execute ();

            $stmt->close ();

            // Check for successful insertion
            if ($result) {
                // User successfully inserted
                return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            } else {
                // Failed to create user
                return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
            }
        } else {
            return PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH;
        }
    } else {
        // User with same email already existed in the db
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

As soon as i remove the api_key parameter like this

```
public function createEmployer($companyName, $email, $password, $confirmPass) {

    $response = array ();

    // First check if user already existed in db
    if (! $this->isEmpExists ( $email )) {



        if ($this->comparePassword ( $password, $confirmPass )) {

            // Generating password hash
            $password_hash = PassHash::hash ( $password );

            // Generating API key
            $api_key = $this->generateApiKey ();

            // insert query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "INSERT INTO company(name, email, password) values(?, ?, ?)" );
            $stmt->bind_param ( "sss", $companyName, $email, $password_hash);

            $result = $stmt->execute ();

            $stmt->close ();

            // Check for successful insertion
            if ($result) {
                // User successfully inserted
                return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            } else {
                // Failed to create user
                return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
            }
        } else {
            return PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH;
        }
    } else {
        // User with same email already existed in the db
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

The function returns USER_CREATE_FAILED

Comment: Table definition? Something indexed/ required? FWIW - the `bindParam` statement looks fishy.

Comment: it works fine when the api_key parameter is there but as soon as i remove it it goes to USER_CREATE_FAILED

Comment: Table: company
Columns:
id int(32) AI PK, 
name varchar(25) ,
email varchar(40) ,
password text ,
api_key varchar(50),

Comment: ok i just figured it out when you mentioned the table definition thing. The api_key attribute is set to NOT NULL so if i remove it that should fix it. thanks